# rowToggle action reset selectOneMenu value in rowExpansion

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have selectOneMenu and inputText in my rowExpansion. Whenever I untoggle and retoggle the specific row or I toggle into another row, the value in my selectOneMenu will reset to my noSelectOption but my inputText value remain there.

I am running on Primefaces 6.0.

```
<p:dataTable id="idTableItemList" value="#{bean.itemList}" var="vo" rowKey="#{row}" rowIndexVar="row" rowExpandMode="single">

    <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{bean.onRowToggle}" global="false" 
        update=":idForm:idTableItemList:idTablePackage" />

    <p:column>
        <p:rowToggler></p:rowToggler> 
    </p:column>

    <p:rowExpansion>

        <p:dataTable id="idTablePackage" value="#{vo.packageList}" var="voSub" rowKey="#{row}"
        rowIndexVar="rowIndex">

            <p:column  headerText="Package Type" style="width:100px;">
                <p:selectOneMenu id="idPackage"
                value="#{voSub.packageType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" /> 
                    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.packageUDCList}" 
                    var="udc" itemLabel="#{udc.description}" itemValue="#{udc.code}"/>
                    <p:ajax update="idPackage" event="change" listener="#{bean.updateItemPackage(vo, voSub)}" global="false"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:column>
            <p:column  headerText="Quantity" style="width:40px;">
                <p:inputNumber id="idQuantity" value="#{voSub.quantity}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

I updated the rowToggle to the code below but still no luck with it.

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener=“#{bean.onRowToggle}" global="false" 
        disabled=“#{bean.itemList.size() eq 0}"
        process=":idForm:idTableItemList:#{bean.rowIndex}:idTablePackage" 
        update=":idForm:idTableItemList:#{bean.rowIndex}:idTablePackage"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Problem Occurs because the data in rowExansion is not send to server , so in the server side the data will be old

when you click at toggle button the row will be removed , not set hidden

you can solve the problem by 
1-add an `<h:link>` at

```
<p:column>
        <p:rowToggler></p:rowToggler> 
        <h:link onclick="makeRowHidden()"/>
</p:column>
```

2- give the h:link an icon
3- make the rowToggler icon hidden

please if you need more details say and i will update my answer

Comment: Can I know what it does in makeRowHidden() function? I do have ajax to update my value in server whenever I change the value in selectOneMenu.

Comment: makeRowHidden() change the style p:dataTable to display:none , and when i collapse again , it will set display:block

Comment: My scenario is bit different, in p:rowExpansion have one selectonemenu and i given ajax call for change event, so for every change of selectonemenu value processing. Now problem is, i have non-ajax call at that time rowExpansion getting collapsed and selectonemenu value setting as empty(""). how to set correct value for this. if i do manual collapse and expand then value not changing (working fine).